# Python 'int' object is not subscriptable - casting doesnt work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting

I'd like to read the last line of a file and then get a substring of it for printing it out.

I've made different approaches but none of them worked.

```
file_temp = os.system('cat "/myfile.csv"|tail -1')
# line looks like that ['08/19/2020 22:30:14', '26.1', '53.2', '82']
test = str(file_temp[25:-16])
print (test)
#same for
print (file_temp[2])
```

this results in the following error:

```
temp_test = str(file_temp[25:-16])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

With or without casting, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The function `os.system()` just returns the exit status of the command. That's an integer value. This means that the variable `file_temp` just holds an integer indicating whether the command was successful. It's not a file.

Comment: os.system return int to file_temp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the last line of a file, this is the wrong command. You have to open the file, read it, and get the line you wanted:

```
file_temp = open("/myfile.csv","r")
lines = file_temp.readlines()
file_temp.close()

print(lines[-1])
```

Comment: Thx, I will try that. Even though if i print(file_temp) i can see the expected result. So the last line is in the variable. The problem is with working with that line.

Comment: What is shown when you `print(type(file_temp))`. Perhaps it's a more complicated object that does not only contain the integer indicating the exit status but also some information on the console returns. You might be able to unpack it and get the line.
But using `open` is much more sensible and will work on all platforms.